# ¿Cómo relacionar post y tags (es decir relacionar múltiples datos a otro dato) en MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

¿Es posible almacenar más de un dato relacional en una columna mysql?
Por ejemplo, si creara entradas para un blog, estos tienen categorías y tags. Generalmente se suelen usar varios tags.
En la BD tendría una tabla más o menos así para las entradas:

| id | titulo_post | tags |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | blog-prueba | tag1, tag2, tag3 |

Y la tabla *tags* sería:

| id | tag |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | tag1 |
| 2 | tag2 |
| 3 | tag3 |

Pero no entiendo cómo se relacionan o hacer que se relacionen. Quisiera crear un pequeño blog con php, sinceramente no entiendo esto.

Comment: Lee por favor sobre normalizacion de bases de datos. Entre las dos tablas, hay una tabla intermedia que tiene el id del post y el id del tag... tu primera tabla esta mal y te va a traer montones de problemas...

Comment: Gracias por tomarte el tiempo de responder tratare de revisar eso

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ésta es la versión normalizada de lo que buscas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que intentas hacer, metiendo todos los tags en el mismo campo, no es recomendable porque pierdes muchas de las posibilidades que te ofrece el SQL de combinar tablas y realizar consultas de agregación de datos. Es como si la información la tuvieras oculta para el motor de la base de datos y tuviera que procesarla antes de poder explotarla directamente.

Te facilito el SQL para que puedas reproducir la estructura:

```
CREATE TABLE posts(
  id_post int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  titulo_post varchar(31)
  );
CREATE TABLE tags(
  id_tag int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  tag varchar(31)
  );
CREATE TABLE referencian(
  id_ref int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  id_post int,
  id_tag int,
  FOREIGN KEY(id_post) REFERENCES posts(id_post),
  FOREIGN KEY(id_tag) REFERENCES tags(id_tag)
  );
```

Introduzco a continuación unos datos de muestra para que visualices el resultado:

```
INSERT INTO posts (titulo_post) VALUES ('blog-prueba');
INSERT INTO tags (tag) VALUES ('tag1'),('tag2'),('tag3');
INSERT INTO referencian (id_post, id_tag) VALUES (1,1),(1,2),(1,3);
```

Con la consulta:

```
SELECT titulo_post,GROUP_CONCAT(tag)
  FROM referencian
  JOIN posts USING(id_post)
  JOIN tags USING(id_tag)
  GROUP BY 1;
```

Obtendrás:

```
+-------------+-------------------+
| titulo_post | GROUP_CONCAT(tag) |
+-------------+-------------------+
| blog-prueba | tag1,tag2,tag3    |
+-------------+-------------------+
```

Que es lo que buscabas originalmente, pero obtenido de unas tablas normalizadas que permiten múltiples procesados por el MySQL, como buscar el tag más usado, el menos popular, etc.

Comment: Gracias por responder me quedo claro eso. Pero la duda que me surgió es como ingresar los datos en la tabla referencian. Entonces el flujo de trabajo que pense para aplicarlo con php es el siguiente no se si sea lo correcto:

Comment: 1. Insertar los datos en la tabla posts
2. Insertar los tags en la tabla tags ya que el formulario tambien cuenta con un input para los tags entonces ya estan capturados seria solo de guardarlos en la tabla tags.
3. Una vez guardado los post y tags hacer una consulta con "SELECT FROM" para sacar el id del post
4. Hacer un "SELECT FROM" a los tags para sacar el id de los tags que iran relacionados al post
5. Teniendo capturado el id del post y el id de los tags guardarlos en la tabla reference
6. Terminar el proceso.

¿No se si esto es lo correcto?

Comment: ma o menos XD hay pasos demas creo ...

Comment: @FerDaniela No entiendo a qué refieres. Modifica tu pregunta añadiendo tu duda o formula una nueva pregunta, indicando qué quieres obtener, qué has hecho para obtenerlo y qué es lo que no te sale... :) El meollo del asunto está en el tercer `INSERT`

Comment: @DavidJP aqui en este escenario no seria combeniente un Procedimiento almacenado... ??? para que solo pase los datos ???

Comment: Si lo estoy entendiendo bien, con el tercer `INSERT` se resuelve. Entiendo que los tags se seleccionarán de una lista en la página web para cada post y, si falta alguno, se añade puntualmente. Estando todos, únicamente hay que ir emparejando post y tag, haciendo las inserciones necesarias.

Comment: Bueno mi duda esencial seria como hago para agregar los datos en la tabla reference. Si ya tengo digamos post de prueba con  id=1 
y en la tabla tags
primera tag con id =1
segundo tag con id =2 
Cual seria el mejor proceso para meter estos datos en reference relacionandolo al post. No se si quedo mas clara mi duda o haber si planteo otro pregunta gracias.

Comment: Ah, sí, sí. Así: `INSERT INTO referencian (id_post,id_tag) VALUES (1,1),(1,2);`

Comment: Cual seria el mejor proceso es una pregunta basada en opiniones... nadie tiene la verdad absoluta... lo que podemos hacer es explicarte los mejores estandares que puedes aplicar que serian 2FN y 3FN

Comment: gracias a todos me quedo un poco mas claro este tema